# How to access current directory with Boot2Docker and Docker?

Tags: python, macos, module, docker, boot2docker

I run Docker container

```
docker run -it python
```

from which I can't see my local files.

How can I mount my current (host) directory (from which I run `docker`)
as current directory inside the docker container?
So that I can

```
import file
```

inside the container and it will find the local `file.py`.

I could only find complicated solutions, where I have to explicitly mount the host directory, which seems to require absolute paths, where I'd like to type something dynamic like `.` as path (doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/:/codedir -it python
```

?

You can't use relative paths like "." in volume commands. If it annoys you that much, try using Docker Compose, which does allow relative paths.

Comment: Err, yeah. How else would you do it? There's no command to place volumes relative to the working directory, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Can't I run a Docker container with my original file system staying in the same directory?